# "Delete" or "Remove". What the word is better for commit messages?

Tags: git, git-rm

My English isn't mother tongue, so I want to understand what the word "delete" or "remove" is better when we commit file deletion? For example:

```
rm commitedLater.file
git add -u
git commit -m "Remove/Delete the unnecessary file"
```

The question may seem strange, but sometimes I'm really confused)

Comment: They're both fine, and neither is ambiguous or confusing which is the most important thing.

Comment: Thanks I think your answer is quite enough for me)

Comment: You could post it as answer

Comment: I actually voted to close as primarily opinion-based, but I'll post an answer if no-one else agrees with that.

Comment: I still can't figure out why people vote to close... Could you explain please what does it mean "opinion-based"?)

Comment: If the question is a subjective matter of opinion or personal preference, rather than an objective matter of fact, it can lead to open-ended discussion an argument because there's no clear correct answer. Here, the English-language part is objective but _"which is better"_ is subjective - hence the only answer addresses the English-language part and ignores the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I would say the words are synonymous.

In the abstract, "delete" has the connotation of destroying the deleted item, whereas "remove" implies only taking it out of a collection.

As in

"I deleted the typo by erasing it",

and

"I removed the page from the tablet, so that I could write on it more easily"